# have form act as a simple redirect (HTML/PhoneGap)

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm making a prototype and the manipulation of the url when submitting a form is causing me issues.  I just want to redirect to the link but keep my styling.

```
<form method = "link" action="portal.html" class="forms">

        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"  />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

I want the submit to act a a straight redirect.. w/ appending the ?username=&password= to the redirect.

If it makes a difference this is an html5 project for android using phonegap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just want to submit the form and go to another page, while appending the form's fields to the URL as a query string (`?foo=bar&foo=bar`). For that you have to declare your form's method as `GET`, like so:

```
<form method="GET" action="portal.html" class="forms">
```

**EDIT**: turns out the desired behavior is exactly the opposite.

To **don't** append a query string, you could set your form's method to `POST`

```
<form method="POST" action="portal.html" class="forms">
```

Comment: I don't even want to submit the form.. I want the submit button to act as simple href.  for example click submit and go to a.html NOT  a.html?username=&password=